# Send Data from JavaScript to Delphi (firemonkey)

Tags: delphi, chromium, firemonkey

[image]

In Delphi , With below code I can send data to Javascript and it work well , but how can send data from Javascript to Delphi ?

first , I Use  below code in Javascript  but did not work :

> JS_DELPHI._geta()  ;

even below code did not work :

> TMyExtension._geta()  ;

I think my code in Delphi have not some essential code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, ceffmx, FMX.Edit ,   ceflib ,
   uCEFBaseRefCounted, uCEFInterfaces, uCEFTypes, uCEFListValue, uCEFBrowser, uCEFFrame, uCEFRequest,
  uCEFv8Context, uCEFv8Exception, uCEFv8StackTrace, uCEFDomNode, uCEFProcessMessage, uCEFApplicationCore;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ChromiumFMX1: TChromiumFMX;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


   type
//这里建议用class  不建议用class(TThread)  不然有些地方要报错
TMyExtension = class(TThread) // or just class, (extension code execute in thread)
  public
  class function _geta:string;
end;

TCustomRenderProcessHandler = class(TCefRenderProcessHandlerOwn)
protected
    procedure OnWebKitInitialized; override;
end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  d : Integer   ;
  m : TMyExtension ;
  CefRenderProcessHandler : TCustomRenderProcessHandler ;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.XLgXhdpiTb.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.SSW3.fmx ANDROID}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ChromiumFMX1.Load('http://localhost/index.html');

 Edit1.Text := '555 ';

  ShowMessage('hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ChromiumFMX1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(' d1();',ChromiumFMX1.browser.MainFrame.GetURL, 0);
end;


class function TMyExtension._geta: string;
begin
ShowMessage('dddddddddddddddddddddddd');
  Result:='salam';
end;

procedure TCustomRenderProcessHandler.OnWebKitInitialized;

begin
    {$IFDEF DELPHI14_UP}
    TCefRTTIExtension.Register('JS_DELPHI', TMyExtension);
  {$ENDIF}
end;



initialization
  CefRemoteDebuggingPort := 9000;
  CefRenderProcessHandler := TCustomRenderProcessHandler.Create;
  CefBrowserProcessHandler := TCefBrowserProcessHandlerOwn.Create;
end.

end.
```

Comment: This question was answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303829/how-to-invoke-the-delphi-function-from-javascript-using-cef4delphi

Comment: can you complete my code?

Comment: Dear please help me to solve this.... i am under presure to solve this question

Comment: If you need a quick solution use console messages to send information from JavaScript to Delphi. Call "console.log()" from JavaScript and use the TChromium.OnConsoleMessage event to get the information. All the code is in the DOMVisitor demo.

Comment: i am a newbie and it's difficult for me ... i must solve upper question.